# Is there a way to set parent device while creating an Azure IoT Hub device using node-red?

Tags: node-red, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am using node red (node-red-contrib-azure-iot-hub) to register the new devices on Azure IoT Hub. The 'Azure IoT Hub Registry' node allows to register new IoT device. I want to set a Parent Device for the new device that I am creating.  However, I am not sure what parameter I should use to set the parent for this new IoT device. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about creating a new downstream device in scenarios where parent device is Edge device?

If so, the property is called 'deviceScope' that should be set. Currently, SDK does not support this(it is in a preview, so not yet released).

This is the [commit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/commit/2705938c873ad2227274dfba480f13883bf46adb#diff-41108a341698508899af777aee0096f4) for C# SDK, so I would assume that in order to have full support you have to wait a little bit more.

Comment: You are correct, this is currently a public preview feature and it is only supported in the C# public preview branch.  We will add this functionality to the Node SDK soon.  With that said, node-red-contrib-azure-iot-hub is a community project and we do not control the release schedule.

Comment: Great, can you or the author please mark it as an answer in that case? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answers and explanation.  I am living with the following constraints.  I have a gateway that I have represented as Edge device.  I have further downstream devices that will connect to Azure through the gateway.  I would need to add these downstream devices as 'IoT devices' to the platform.  My gateway communicates over MQTT and I dont have a luxury to make a change to the gateway code.  Will appreciate if you can suggest a work around.

Comment: Can you please suggest what could be the possible value-format for the 'deviceScope'.  I tried '<parent device id>' and also '"ms-azure-iot-edge://<parent device id>.  However, in both the cases it fails to create the device.

Comment: How did you create the device? Can you share the code? I would advise avoiding creating a device identity from the device itself. That is a serious security issue. Either do it through the cloud, or by using DPS(the best option). I am also hoping that DPS will provide a mechanism to resolve that, as it is advertised with 'zero-touch' provisioning, but till then I think it is not clear how this would/should be used.

Comment: I am using node red (node-red-contrib-azure-iot-hub) to register the new devices on Azure IoT Hub. The 'Azure IoT Hub Registry' node allows to register new IoT device.  I got to know that node-red-contrib-azure-iot-hub is third party component and doesn't yet support  to set the parent for this new IoT device.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Great. Can you please mark my comment above as an answer? Thanks!